# If $T: V \to V$ is a linear operator such that $T^5 = T^4$, then $\ker T^4 \cap Im\ T^4 $ is a singleton.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$I have to prove or disprove

> If $T: V \to V$ is a linear operator such that $T^5 = T^4$, then  $\ker
>  T^4 \cap \Im T^4 $ is  a singleton. Here $\ker$ stands for the kernel
>   and $\Im$ stands for the image space of $V$ respectively. Can we also show that $V$ is direct sum of $\ker T^4$ and $\Im T^4$.

**My approach** Let $x \in \ker
T^4 \cap \Im T^4$. Then $x \in \ker
T^4 $ and  $\Im T^4$. Now $x \in \ker
T^4 $ implies that $T^4(x) = 0$ and $x \in \Im T^4$ implies that there must exist  $w \in V$ such that $T^4(w) = x$. From here I am not able to proceed. I need help.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Let $S = T^4$, and show that $S^2 = S$.

Comment: For such $x$ you have $x=T^4(w)=T^5(w)=TT^4(w)=TT^5(w)=T^2T^4(w)=T^2T^5(w)=...=T^4T^4(w)=T^4(x)=0$.

Comment: @flan looks like a complete answer!

Comment: For the second part note that $x=(I-T^4)x+T^4x$, that $T^4(I-T^4)x=T^4x-T^8x=T^4x-T^4x=0$, therefore $(I-T^4)x$ is in the kernel of $T^4$ and that $T^4x$ is in the image of $T^4$. Therefore, the sum of the kernel and the image of $T^4$ is the whole space. The first part tells you that the sum is direct.

Comment: @flan Thanks for the comment. Why don't you write this in answer. I understood completely. It will help others too. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer inspired in no small part by the comments of our colleague flan:

We observe that

$(T^4)^2 = T^8 = T^5T^3 = T^4T^3 = T^5T^2$
$= T^4T^2 = T^5T = T^4T = T^5 = T^4;   \tag 1$

that is, $T^4$ is *idempotent*; for idempotent operators $P$ we have

$P^2 = P,   \tag 2$

and this implies

$\ker P \cap \text{Im} P = \{0\}, \tag 3$

for if

$y \in \ker P \cap \text{Im} P,   \tag 4$

then

$\exists z, \; y = Pz \tag 5$

and

$Py = 0; \tag 6$

then

$y = Pz = P^2z = PPz = Py = 0, \tag 7$

and we have (3); with

$P = T^4, \tag 8$

this shows that

$\ker T^4 \cap \text{Im} T^4 = \{0\}, \tag 9$

a singleton.

We also have, for any vector $y$

$y = y - Py + Py = (I - P)y + Py, \tag{10}$

and with $P$ idempotent

$P(I - P)y = (P - P^2)y = 0, \tag{11}$

that is

$(I - P)y \in \ker P,  \tag{12}$

whence *via* (10),

$y \in \ker P + \text{Im} P, \tag{13}$

and this in concert with (3) shows that

$V = \ker P \oplus \text{Im} P; \tag{14}$

since $T^4$ is idempotent, it follows that

$V = \ker T^4 \oplus \text{Im} T^4, \tag{15}$

as per request.  $OE\Delta$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its very clear.

Answer (score 0):

By reduction to absurd.
We suposse that exists $0 \neq a \in Ker T^{4} \cap Im T^{4}$. Then we considerer $w \in (T^{4})^{-1}(a)$ and we have that:
$a=T^{4}(w)=T^{5}(w)=T(T^{4}(w))=T(a)$
So we have that $0=T^{4}(a)=a$ but $a \neq 0$. ABSURD!!!!
So $Ker T^{4} \cap Im T^{4} = \{0\}$ and is a singleton.